# Nuget dependency not found after xcopying from release directory

Tags: asp.net, dependencies, nuget, webapi

Have an ASP.NET Core Kestrel based web API in which everything works fine when being xcopied from \release to intended working directory. But when activating Windows Authentication with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate` package, I get a

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.DirectoryServices.Protocols, Version=6.0.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

exception after copying the content from \release to the intended working directory and firing the executable (app.Run() in program.cs is the crashing instruction).

The assembly in question is a direct dependency of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate` package, and among the files in \release and in the working directory there is a `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.dll`. Whats wrong?

OS is Windows Server 2019, VS 2022 builds into /release, VS 2022 post build event copies files.

Minimal sample here: https://github.com/olaflischke/WebApiWithAuth

Comment: When does the exception happen? When you are copying the data or when the application starts? How do you populate the `\release` folder?

Comment: At app.Run() in program.cs - updated my question accordingly.

Comment: How do you populate the `/release` folder? What is the environment your are building and running on?

Comment: The OS is Windows Server 2019, the copying is being done by a few code lines in the post build event using VS 2022, release folder is created and managed by VS 2022.

Comment: So you just build the app in the release mode and then copy the files?

Comment: Affirmative, thats the way we work.

Comment: Have you tried using publish functionality? Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Here's the sample: https://github.com/olaflischke/WebApiWithAuth - create a c:\tmp\test.api directory manually and start the executable found there after build. Beware, console closes rather quick after exception.

Comment: I'm not at my Windows machine right now and will try to look at it next week.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem** is: The nuget dependencies go to some subfolder /runtime within the /release folder and are referenced there.

**1. Solution:** Include that /runtime folder in the copy script. *Disadvantage:* You are copying subfolders for linux and osx which you probably never will need when you're going to deploy to windows only.

**2. Solution:** Don't use nuget. Copy the required assemblies (here: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.dll and System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.dll) to your solution folder, reference them and set their "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Always". Delete the nuget references from your solution. *Disadvantage:* No updates by nuget mechanisms.

Further suggestions highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, downgrading System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement from the version 7.0 to 6.0 has solved it.

Comment: As you might see in the exception message we're on .NET 6. System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement as well.